# how to install eclipse .tar.gz with dual boot at windows?

Tags: 14.04

I am new to Ubuntu and want to learn how to install
the software .I downloaded .tar.gz file file and I
have no idea what to do with it. Let me tell you that
I use dual boot Ubuntu with windows and I have
stored in d drive suggest me what to do? I had
downloaded the non source file of eclipse. The
answered question is confusing and not for dual boot
If you do not know the answer just say it , don't mark duplicate or delete post.

Comment: Your dual boot system has no any connection with the eclipse install. If you install the app in Ubuntu, download the package for Ubuntu or generic Linux!

Comment: please tell step by step. 
I have downloaded via eclipse site.
I don't know the terminal

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract "eclipse.tar.gz" and run "eclipse".
No installation needed.
Also I suggest to extract it to your home folder (Linux) or C:\ (Windows).

Comment: yeah I tried but no option in computer folder I am unable to do that.
IT says app missing.

Comment: its pretty easy just untar the file via command tar xvzf filename.tar.gz



and all done just open directory and double click the file.